# Updating Large MySQL Database very often

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a large mysql DB connected to a PHP web application. I'm looking to store upwards of 10-50 million rows of user data.

**My question is:** what is the best way to update 500,000 rows as often as possible from a public web API? Specifically, update the data, when the data changes in the API.

Comment: 50 million rows isn't prohibitive nor are half a million updates, they won't be quick but that is hardware dependent. However without specifying how and what you are actually processing it isn't easy to offer any advice.

Comment: i can try to be a bit more helpful i guess. The data is simple statistics, all ints, all coming in as json from a simple web api. my intentions were to iterate through rows in the DB that haven't been updated in, lets say 30 min, and update them via the api requests. i thought to do all of this via a cron job and some php. however, i don't believe this is right way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

you should know about BIG DATA, maybe you can using hadoop for engine..

[ABOUT BIG DATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_data)

[HADOOP](https://hadoop.apache.org/)

Comment: This is a great place to start, considering the vagueness of the question being asked. Hadoop is a good system for processing that large amount of data. As Wahyu is suggesting, read up on it and see if it is in alignment with what you're working with, and what you're working on.